# Unable to import module 'src/index': Error at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I deployed some changes to a TypeScript project using `serverless`, I added this code and called it elsewhere:

```
import Mixpanel = require('mixpanel')

export default Mixpanel.init(process.env.MIXPANEL_TOKEN)
```

When I now invoke the AWS Lambda function, I receive this error message in my logs:

> Unable to import module 'src/index': Error at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)

How can I find out more about the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the `MIXPANEL_TOKEN` environment variable to the `serverless.yml` fixed this:

```
service: my-service

plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-typescript
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-prune-plugin

...

functions:

  my-function:
    handler: src/index.default
    events:
      - http:
          path: /
          method: post
    environment:
      MIXPANEL_TOKEN: ${env:MIXPANEL_TOKEN}

...
```